# Stopping googlebot from following links in javascript

Tags: jquery, seo, web-crawler, bots, googlebot

While looking over my google bot errors one of them was a 403 error from a directory link I never put anywhere. After searching around in that page for a bit I found that google followed a link it found in some javascript code, this code in particular:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: 'post',
        url: '/data/pages/' + r,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#mainbox').animate({"height": a}, 80, function() {
```

The google bot doesn't understand the + r part of it and keeps giving me errors about this. I know you can add a rel="nofollow" to anchors to tell googlebot not to follow them, but is there a way you can do this with script tags? (I searched around a lot and couldn't find a good answer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

specify in your [robots.txt which links google bot](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=156449) can follow

Comment: So if I say Disallow: /data/pages/ will it understand not to go there?

Answer (score 1):

[Matt Cutts just released a video on this very topic](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LW3pjQeCqqk).  In it he recommends using robots.txt for Javascript files.  However, he states:

> It turns out that as we are executing JavaScript, we do look at the attributes.  So you can actually use Javascript and put, like, a nofollow attribute on individual URLs.

Its not clear to me what the syntax for putting a nofollow into javascript would be.  I have asked about it here:  https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/46659/14543